# fitting a logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, regression

```
    rotenone <- data.frame(dose=factor(c("high", "medium", "low")),
                       affected=c(44, 24, 0),
                       total=c(50, 46, 49))
    print(rotenone)

     dose affected total
 ##1   high       44    50
 ##2 medium       24    46
 ##3    low        0    49



    rotenone_logit_mod <- glm(affected ~ 1 + dose, data = rotenone, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
    summary(rotenone_logit_mod)
```

above is my code for comparing the proportion of affected insects in the three groups by fitting a logistic regression model.

but the error is:
"Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1"

can someone please help me fix the problem?
thank you

Comment: A logistic regression looks at a binary dependent variable (1 or 0). You have three levels. Since these are ordered (low, medium, high), you would likely need to extend the model to ordinal logistic regression, which can handle more than two categories.

Comment: we've had two questions with an almost identical setup in the last hour. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71505729/fitting-a-logistic-regression-model-in-r). What course is this from?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your dataframe, which can't look like this:

```
rotenone <- data.frame(dose=factor(c("high", "medium", "low")),
                       affected=c(44, 24, 0),
                       total=c(50, 46, 49))
```

If you want to fit a logistic regression model you have to modify your data: the outcome variable has to be a binary one (0 for not affected and 1 for affected). If you are not familiar with `dplyr` you could do it like that:

```
rotenone %<>% mutate(not_affected = total-affected, .after = affected)
df_affected <- data.frame(dose = rep(rotenone$dose, 
                                     times = rotenone$affected),
                          affected = 1)
df_not_affd <- data.frame(dose = rep(rotenone$dose, 
                                     times = rotenone$not_affected),
                          affected = 0)
rotenone_mod <- rbind.data.frame(df_affected, df_not_affd)
```

Look at the summary of your new dataframe, it should match the values of your old one:

```
summary(rotenone_mod)
```

That is the case, so now you can fit your model:

```
rotenone_logit_mod <- glm(affected ~ 1 + dose, 
                          data = rotenone_mod, 
                          family = binomial(link = "logit"))
summary(rotenone_logit_mod)
```